# Magento modify collection object element value

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, collection

I want to modify collection object element value without using `$collection->getData()` as `getData()` is returning an array. But I want an object to be returned.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')
                ->getCollection();

$i = 0; 
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    //$collection[$i]['flat_last_order_amount'] = '39.99';
    //$collection[$i]['products_sku'] = '4361-4361';
    $i++;
}
```

I tried with commented code(with using `getData()`) but its not working. Any other way to do this please.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the magic getters / setters from `Varien_Object`.

You can do something like this:

```
foreach ($collection as $object) {
    $object->setFlatLastOrderAmount("39.99");
    $object->setProductsSku('4361-4361');
    $object->save();
}
```

Only call the `save` method if you need to save the changes in the database.

If you need to reuse that collection with updated values you can do the following after the loop:

```
$collection->clear();
$collection->load();
```

Comment: after foreach completed when I print $collection it gives me old values only.

Comment: @Niteen see my update

Comment: No Raphael, its not working. I used it after for loop is completed.